# deployJava.js does not support IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, deployjava

The function 'getBrowser' returned 'Detected browser name:**Netscape Family, Other**'.
Has someone improved this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/02/internet-explorer-11-dont-call-me-ie/

According to the above, we can search 'trident' in the userAgent string.

Comment: In function 'testUsingActiveX', also need to remove the following code:            if (typeof ActiveXObject == 'undefined' || !ActiveXObject) {
                if (this.debug) {
                    alert('Browser claims to be IE, but no ActiveXObject object?');
                }
                return false;
            }